# Delete Characters from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a list which contains multiple words and unsupported characters as well :

for eg:

```
{é, â, ê, î, ô, û, c, re, be}
```

I want to remove all of the above characters from a list without creating another list to store these characters.

I don't want to use:

```
Complement[foo, bar]
```

I want to keep all of the words in the list but remove the other characters.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean - can you provide a more concrete example, i.e. an example input and the expected output?

Comment: What is wrong with `Complement[{é, â, ê, î, ô, û, c, re, be}, {é, â, ê, î, ô, û}]`?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi He doesn't want to explicitly list all special characters that can occur. That would be a long list.

Comment: It would be nice if you could clarify exactly what you want. I interpret your requirement as the removal of _all_ of the characters in `{é, â, ê, î, ô, û, c, re, be}` from another list without having to explicitly supply an exclusion list. But others have interpreted things differently. And as per your comment, you also want to exclude _all_ single letters.  But what about `re` and `be`? Just these two words, or all two-letter words? And what about `research` and `robe`?

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like:

```
list = {"é", "â", "ê", "î", "ô", "û", "c", "re", "be"};
Select[list, 
  And[
     StringQ[#],
     StringLength[#] > 1 || Between[First @ ToCharacterCode[#], {48, 122}]
  ]&
]
```

> {"c", "re", "be"}

The character range `{48, 122}` corresponds to letters without diacritics and numbers. You can change it as needed.

Comment: I also have some unsupported characters in the list, can this code be edited such that only the words are present in the list. Remove everything except the words. Even remove single letters like : {"a","b","c","d"}

Comment: thanks for the help, I figured it out :)

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {"é", "â", "ê", "î", "ô", "û", "c", "re", "be"};

Select[# == RemoveDiacritics[#] &] @ list
```

> ```
> {"c", "re", "be"}
> ```

```
Intersection[#, RemoveDiacritics @ #]& @ list
```

> ```
> {"be", "c", "re"}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex solution which uses a [negative look-ahead](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) ( `(?!foo)` ) to exclude `re` and `be`, and then selects everything containing A-Z or a-z or 0-9 provided that each match is two or more characters in length.

```
lst//Pick[#,StringContainsQ[lst, 
  RegularExpression["^(?!(\\bre\\b)|(\\bbe\\b))([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})$"]]]&
```

> {research, my, string, bet, are, robe}

From the OP comment ("Remove everything except the words. Even remove single letters like: {"a","b","c","d"}), perhaps this is what is required?

That is, I am assuming that the OP wants to exclude everything less than two characters in length, wants no special characters, and in addition wants to exclude `re` and `be` (but not `research` or `robe`)

**lst**

```
lst={"\[CapitalEAcute]","a","c", "re", "research","my", "string", "be", "bet", "are","robe"}
```